# Keep my function from blocking functionality while getting info

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function with a completion handler that works to download videos from youtube's API.

On the first run, it works great. On subsequent runs, since the videos are stored in the device, and shown before the array of videos is updated, I would like for the user to be able to interact with the table, while it is updated (if required). However, while the information is being downloaded, the interaction with the table or the app is blocked.

I guess this has something to do with Grand Central Dispatch, but I don't know how to use it.

```
    Networking().getPlaylists() { (result: String) -> () in
        self.activityView.removeFromSuperview()
        print("should reload data")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Could somebody give me some pointers?

Comment: If the UI is blocked while this query is running, the problem undoubtedly rests inside the `Network` implementation. You should share how it's performing the request. But if you use `NSURLSession` inside `Networking` (and don't do anything like semaphores or waiting for operations to complete), it really shouldn't block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually not Alamofire that was blocking my UI (it is actually an async function), but it was SwiftyJSON while I was parsing. I solved it by dispatching_async but over the parsing section and not the rest of the function!

See more here: [Alamofire http json request block ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050349/alamofire-http-json-request-block-ui)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your network code would execute on a background thread:

```
func getPlaylists() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        //Do network stuff
    })
}
```

but also before you call your completion, make sure you flip back to the main thread before you do UI logic like updating your tableview:

```
func getPlaylists() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        //Do network stuff
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion(results)
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: The view still seems to pause while its getting the information! Is there anything else I might be doing wrong?